# How to call ThenInclude twice in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core API app, and relying on EF Core. I have entities defined like this:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Post.Author))]
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual AppUser Author { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Like.Post))]
    public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; } = new List<Like>();

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Comment.Post))]
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
}
```

Where `Comment` and `Like` are some other entities. Please note that I have simplified the entities for brevity. Then, I want to get the `Posts` of a user, but also include the `Likes` and `Comments` that a post has gotten. So, I did something like this:

```
return _context.Users
               .Include(u => u.Location)
               .Include(u => u.Posts)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Comments)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Owner)
               .Include(u => u.Posts)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Likes)
                        .ThenInclude(l => l.Giver)
               .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, this works fine, but as you can see I'm calling `.Include(u = u.Posts)` twice. Is there a way to call `ThenInclude` twice on same property, without actually writing the `Include` statement also twice?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot use `ThenInclude` with multiple navigation properties. You have to have `Include`.

Here is [bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4716) opened for this.

Comment: I notice that specifying the full path in an Include also works, e.g. 
Include(u => u.Posts)
.Include(u => u.Posts.Comments)
Is this equivalent? Any downsides?

Answer (score 255):

> Now, this works fine, but as you can see I'm calling .Include(u = u.Posts) twice. Is there a way to call ThenInclude twice on same property, without actually writing the Include statement also twice?

Calling `Include(u => u.Posts)` twice is the right way to do it.

From [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels)... emphasis on the last sentence.

> You may want to include multiple related entities for one of the entities that is being included. For example, when querying `Blog`s, you include `Posts` and then want to include both the `Author` and `Tags` of the `Posts`. To do this, you need to specify each include path starting at the root. For example, `Blog -> Posts -> Author` and `Blog -> Posts -> Tags`. **This does not mean you will get redundant joins, in most cases EF will consolidate the joins when generating SQL.**

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Tags)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Good time for Microsoft to implement `AlsoInclude()` to prevent you from having to write the same include statement multiple times

Comment: I typed AlsoInclude without knowing no such exists!!

Comment: you right Junior AlsoInclude() or Includes() is a good to implement

Comment: This does not mean you will get redundant joins, in most cases EF will consolidate the joins when generating SQL.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Author)
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Tags)
    .ToList();
```

I see the TSql Query of this, and its OK

Comment: NB: This does not work for EFCore (v7). You have to use `.Include()` with `.ThenInclude()`. See @Jan Paolo Go's answer above.

Comment: It works with a single reference but not with list